# How to send Json data in payload as Toast or Tile Notification in Windows Phone

Tags: json, push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

I want to send Json data in payload as Toast or Tile Notification in Windows Phone as shown below:

```
string msg =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
       "<wp:Toast>" +
       "<wp:Text1><string></ltwp:Text1>" +
       "<wp:Text2><string></wp:Text2>" +
       "<wp:Json><data></wp:Json>" +
       "</ltwp:Toast>" +
    "</wp:Notification>";
```

If it is possible, will I be able to receive the Json in ShellToastNotificationReceived event handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameters with values like following :

```
string msg =
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
  "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
  "<wp:Toast>" +
  "<wp:Text1><string></ltwp:Text1>" +
  "<wp:Text2><string></wp:Text2>" +
  "<wp:Param>/Home.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
  "</ltwp:Toast>" +
  "</wp:Notification>";`
```

- If your app is running in foreground then `PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)` is fired and in `e.Collection[key]` you can find the message you sent.
- If your app is not running in the foreground then on tapping the toast notification app gets launched and is navigated to the specified page(here `/Home.xaml`). In the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` event of the page you can find the parameters you passed and can use them.

So you can give it a try by sending json string in the parameter values and can use them in your app.I have not tried it.This information might be useful for you.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send generic content you should instead use a [Raw Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202977%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). This can contain whatever content you wish.

The limitation of the raw notification is that it can't be received if your app is not running so you may want to send a Toast (or tile) notification to the device and then when the app is subsequently launched trigger the sending of the raw notification.
Of course if you're making a web request to trigger sending a single raw message it will probably be better to just send the payload in response to the trigger request.

Comment: So there is no way to send the custom data in Toast notification msg?

Comment: @Vivek You could send it but it would have to be in one of the defined fields/properties and so it would be displayed to the user and subject to length limitations. There is no way to send additional/custom information in a toast or tile message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more small query if you can answer it. If I discard the notification and launch the app manually, will I still receive the notification in the event handler?

Comment: @Vivek I don't think so but try it and check